# need some assistance with my recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

Write a recursive function count(x, s), which counts and returns how many times x
is at the highest level in the list s.
Example: The call count(4, [1, 4, 2, ['a', [ [ 4 ] , 3, 4] ] ] ) should return 1.

here's my code:

```
def count(x, l):
     if type(l) != list:
         return None
     elif l[0] == x:
         return 0
     else:       
        i = count(x, l[1:])        
        if i is not None:
            return  1 + i                     
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = [1, 4, 2, ['a', [ [ 4 ] , 3, 4] ] ]
    print(count(4, l))
```

In the given example, it works fine. It returns 1 as it should. But when I try to do some test cases, it fails. I'll provide the test cases down below. Any lead on what I am doing wrong here would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
l = [1, 'a', 3, 7, 1, [1, 4]]  #list
count('a', l)                  #should return 1
count(1, l)                    #should return 3
count(4, l)                #should return 1
count([1, 4], l)           #should return 1
count('x', l)              #should return 0
```

P.s can't use any builtin libraries.

Comment: What is the "highest level" here? 4 is once on every level in your example. Your additional examples contain syntax errors: superfluous parentheses, and probably something wrong with lines like `count(4, l), 1)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Are you certain you don't get errors?  The last three lines have syntax errors.   ie.  for ```count(4, l), 1)```   You have an extra ```, 1)```.

Comment: Apologies, @Grismar, and @ewokx; they were just typing mistakes. 
and by highest level, I mean the function should search for the element on the highest level list just (not going into the nested list).

Comment: `count(1, l)  #should return 3` - why? There's only 2 1's there in the outer list. You said that's what you meant by "the highest level"? Why should it return 3? And how is what you're trying to do different from simply `l.count(4)`? (also, naming a variable `l` is generally a bad idea, and good editors will warn you of this - `l`, `I` and `1` are hard to keep apart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def count(x,l,n=0):
    r=[]
    for v in l:
        if x == v:
            n+=1
        else:
            if type(v) in (tuple,list):
                r.append(v)
    while r:
        return count(x,r.pop(),n=n)

    return n

             


if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = [1, 4, 2, ['a', [ [ 4 ,2,5,[[],[4,[4]]]] , 3, 4] ] ]
    print(count(4, l))
```